# Just Enough Administration - Command returning 'Priviledge not held.'

Tags: powershell, least-privilege

I have registered a PowerShell Configuration for use but am running into some difficulties. The desire was to implement a configuration that would allow a service account to remote into a server and restart it without allowing it the ability to perform anything else, naturally JEA seemed like the best fit.  I registered the configuration with the following:

```
#Create Role Capability file
$ServerRestartRole2012 = @{
    Path    = "$env:ProgramFiles\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\JEAServerRestart\RoleCapabilities\ServerRestarter.psrc"
    Author  = "xx"
    Company = "xx"
    VisibleCmdlets = 'Restart-Computer'
    ModulesToImport = 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Management'
}
New-PSRoleCapabilityFile @ServerRestartRole2012

#Create JEA Config
$ServerRestartConfig2012 = @{
    Path                = "$env:ProgramData\JEA\JEAServerRestart.pssc"
    Author              = "xx"
    Description         = "Allows for service account to reboot servers for Server Management Application"
    SessionType         = "RestrictedRemoteServer"
    TranscriptDirectory = "$env:windir\Logs"
    RunAsVirtualAccount = $true
    RoleDefinitions     = @{'xx\D7_APP_ServerRestart' = @{ RoleCapabilities = 'ServerRestarter'}}
}
New-PSSessionConfigurationFile @ServerRestartConfig2012

Register-PSSessionConfiguration -Name ServerRestarters -Path "$env:ProgramData\JEA\JEAServerRestart.pssc"
Restart-Service -Name WinRM
```

The registration is successful and I can enter the session with an account contained in the 'D7_APP_ServerRestart' group. Using `Get-Command` results in what I would expect, but when running `Restart-Computer` the message that is returned explains `Privilege not held` Am I missing part of the setup process?

The server with the registered EndPoint is a 2012R2

[resulting output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qi9P1.jpg)

Comment: well, to me it looks correct, but I'm mostly commenting to find this later and look at the solution ;)

Comment: Crossing my fingers for something :)

Comment: well, i don't know exactly, but to me it seems like something is wrong, can you try to add like get-process and see if it executes correctly?

Comment: I'm really not sure, I've never used role capability, but it seems to me all you're doing here is granting permission to run the PS cmdlet `restart-server` you're not actually giving the role/group server-level permission to restart the server? Have you granted the D7_APP_ServerRestart group 'shut down the system' user rights?

Comment: My understanding of JEA is that that wouldn't be required. When running in a JEA configuration that is set to run as a virtual account, the virtual account is provisioned with full local admin rights, but is only capable of running the commands visible to it based on the role capability file.  Is that a mis-understanding on my part?

Comment: @4c74356b41 - adding restart-service allowed me to run the `restart-service` cmdlet without issue. Still experiencing an issue with restart-computer tohugh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, after playing around a bit I found a resolution. Specifying a different protocol for the `restart-computer` cmdlet to use allowed it to restart the remote server.

`restart-computer -force` fails with `Permission not held`

`restart-computer -protocol WSMan -force` Performed a successful remote reboot

I'm sure there is a valid reason for this, I just haven't been able to find the documentation to support it.

Hopefully this will prevent future headaches for new JEA users.